# Full screen background breaks into white spaces on iPad when scrolling

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css, ipad

I have a problem with the background image not displaying properly. When the page loads it looks ok but when you scroll down the page there are white gaps between each 100% width/height panels (divs). I've read numerous issues with others having the same problem but they don't have any answers and the ones I did read recommended by adding overflow-x:hidden to the body, html which actually works for the iPhone however, doesn't for the iPad..

I was wondering if there is a solution for this; Here is my CSS;

```
.panel {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-size: 100%;
  font-family: FranklinGothicLTCom-BkCm, "Arial Narrow", sans-serif;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
}
```

I added this class to every panel for basic specs, while panel1, panel2 and so on look like this..

```
.panel2 {
  background-color: #e16429;
  background: url(../img/home/background-panel01.jpg) no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 950 !important;
}
```

Take note: This doesn't give the white space in landscape but only portrait, the classes given under portrait media query for iPad look like this..

```
.panel2 {
    background: url(../img/home/background-panel01.jpg) no-repeat center center;
}
```

Here is the live site that I'm working on for futher inspection: http://bit.ly/1eGCShX

If anyone knows this issue and a way to fix it, I couldn't thank you enough. I've been struggling with this for awhile.. Have a great week everyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I may have answered my own question by adding background-size: cover to the div classes under the media query for portrait iPads.

```
panel2 {
     background: url(../img/home/background-panel01.jpg) no-repeat center center;
     -webkit-background-size: cover !important;
     background-size: cover !important;   
  }
```

I thought the bg cover would carry over from it's default class that intially already had background-size cover. I do have a small border now on my third panel, but the main issue was fixed by adding this.